# How to get back ajax request sent to the controller on the view

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div class="button dropdown">
      <select name="languageSelected" required="required" id="languageselector">
        <option value="">Select the language</option>
        @foreach($reviewForm_language as $lang)
         <option value="{{$lang->id}}">{{$lang->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>

    </div>
</form>
```

On selection; it makes a ajax request

```
 <script>    
   $(function() {
    // when select changes
    $('#languageselector').on('change', function() {
        // create data from form input(s)
        let formData = $('#myForm').serialize();

        // send data to your endpoint
        $.ajax({
            url: '/selected/languageId',
            method: 'post',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response); 
            }
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

The route

```
Route::post('/selected/languageId','ProfileController@selectedLangId');
```

On the controller

```
public function selectedLangId(Request $request)
{
    \Log::info("Was here");
    return response()->json(['success'=> $request->languageSelected]);
}
```

This works well up to this point.

How do I get the `$request->languageSelected` passed to the controller back on the view? I would like to be assigned as a PHP variable to be used elsewhere.

Anyone?

Comment: You should already be able to see it it the console. Without a page refresh, keep using JavaScript.

Comment: @LucienDubois I would like to use it in PHP...

Comment: @User101 do you want to return a view as response ?

Comment: @Md.SukelAli I want to return the variable passed to the controller `languageSelected` back to the view

Comment: destroy `options` from `select` and rebuild it once ajax is success.

Answer (score 0):

You're already sending it through 
`['success'=> $request->languageSelected]`

Just need to print it on your success call of blade by 
 `console.log(response.success);`

Comment: My challenge is getting the submitted request and assigning it to a variable to be used in the blade. I want to assign the variable to PHP

Comment: You cannot do that, as PHP variables exist only on server side while the request is handled by the server to build the response to the browser and not on the client side. If you want to do something on your view based on the ajax response, you should handle it with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

if you'r route registered in web.php you need to whitelist url in `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware like below

```
protected $except = [
    'url',
];
```

Comment: This is well taken care of.... Requests are hitting the controller.... My challenge is getting the submitted request and assigning it to a PHP variable to be used in the blade.

Comment: i didn't get that assign to variable part but if you want to display in the browser.

       ` $.ajax({
            url: '/selected/languageId',
            method: 'post',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(response) {
             $('.classname').text(response.success)

            }
        });`

Comment: I mean how do I display the response on the browser?

Comment: can you please tell what do you want with that response ?

Comment: I want to use the selected option to display different forms based on the selection. I want to save the variable as a PHP variable